# mySQL: percentage that received a property each year

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get percentage of CustomerID that received a PropertyID each year where receiving a PropertyID from a client that they had never worked with in the past. For example, ClientID = 2 would be the client that had never worked with in the past. Meaning, the CustomerID has only had 1 PropertyID associated with this Client over the years. How would I query this?

```
PropertyID  ClientID    CustomerID  Date
      10    1                 35    2004
      20    1                 35    2004
      30    1                 37    2004
      40    1                 35    2004
      50    1                 35    2004
      60    *2*               35    2004
      70    3                 37    2004
      80    3                 37    2004
      90    3                 35    2004
     100    3                 35    2004
     110    *2*               37    2005
     120    3                 37    2005
     130    3                 37    2005
     140    3                 37    2005
     150    3                 37    2005
     160    1                 35    2005
     170    1                 35    2005
     180    1                 35    2005
     190    1                 35    2005
```

Expected Result.

```
Year    Customer Percentage
 2004         %
 2005         %
```

Comment: i don't understand how you arrive at '1%'

Comment: I'm unclear by what you mean by "ClientID = 2 would be the client that had never worked with in the past". Can you be more clear about the numerator and denominator of the calculation in your expected result?

Comment: For example, ClientID = 2 would be the client that had never worked with in the past. Meaning, the CustomerID has only had 1 PropertyID associated with this Client over the years.